# A little confused on the '$' character in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell and I'm trying to understand these basic lines of code. I have a main module that's very simple:

```
main = do
       words <- readFile "test.txt"
       putStrLn $ reverseCharacters words
```

where `reverseCharacters` is defined in another module that I have:

```
reverseCharacters :: String -> String
reverseCharacters x = reverse x
```

What I am having trouble understanding is why the `$` needs to be there. I've read previous posts and looked it up and I'm still having difficulty understanding this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `putStrLn $ reverseCharacters words` = `putStrLn (reverseCharacters words)`. Dropping the `$` would make it `putStrLn reverseCharacters words` = `(putStrLn reverseCharacters) words`, which is not what you want. So the `$` doesn't "need" to be there, as you put it, but in this case it helps you get rid of parentheses. (Note also that `$` is just a normal function, not special syntax or anything like that).

Answer (score 10):

`$` is an operator, just like `+`. What it does is treat its first argument (the expression on the left) as a function, and apply it to its second argument (the expression on the right).

So in this case `putStrLn $ reverseCharacters words` is equivalent to `putStrLn (reverseCharacters words)`. It needs to be there because function application is left associative, so using no `$` or parentheses like `putStrLn reverseCharacters words` would be equivalent to parenthesising this way `(putStrLn reverseCharacters) words`, which doesn't work (we can't apply `putStrLn` to `reverseCharacters` [something of type `String -> String`], and even if we could we can't apply the result of `putStrLn` to `words` [something of type `String`]).

The `$` operator is just another way of explicitly "grouping" the words than using parentheses; because it's an infix operator it forces a "split" in the expression (and because it's a very low precedence infix operator, it works even if the things on the left or right are using other infix operators).

Comment: It's also useful if you need a "take a function and apply it to this value" function.

Comment: What @Cubic means is that it's convenient to write `($ x)` instead of `\k -> k x`, such as in `map ($ 4) [foo, bar, baz] == [foo 4, bar 4, baz 4]`.